# Determine current user (Gmail contextual gadget)

Tags: authentication, gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I wrote a gadget for Gmail and I want to make a request from it to my server.
I have read this tutorial [Validating Signed Requests](http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=Validating_Signed_Requests)
Now I know that a request to my server comes from google, but how to find out from what particular Gmail user?

Comment: Ok, I have opensocial_owner_id and opensocial_viewer_id. How can I get the username and the user email? This page http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/best_practices.html#gadget_sso represents only client side JavaScript code, but what about server side code?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know of, is to use OAuth to get one of Googles API feeds (Docs, Contacts, etc.). In each of these feeds, there are these fields, that give you the name and email of the authenticated user:

- feed.author.name.$t
- feed.author.email.$t

Using OAuth however means, that the user needs to grant access to docs / contacts (or what API you are using) within the gadget. So you don't have this information until the user grants access.